# Don't let the WEbView create new Tabs

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am creating a `WebView` browser App.

I want to know that some websites uses ads system on videos so when they click on play button It opens a new tab in stock browser, but I have only one `WebView` and don't have any kind of ad system in it so is it possible to block that system which loads urls like that into a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could help you:

```
WebSettings settings = yourWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
```

More on `WebSettings` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html).

Comment: Thanks Mauker I Searched through But Didn't paid attention to it.Really Thanks Mauker